# Trouble Solving a Differential Equation via Fourier Transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-transform

Consider the following differential equation:

$$y''+2\omega_0 y'+\omega_0^2 y=A_0I(t)$$

where $I$ is the indicator function for the interval $(-\tau,\tau)\subset\mathbb{R}$. Suppose we seek solutions which are continuous $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ functions. Then we can solve this via Fourier transform and then invert the transformation via contour integration. I did arrive at a solution, but not the one that I expected. The solution that I obtained has a discontinuity at $t=\tau$. How can this be possible despite the prior assumption that $y$ be a continuous $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ function? For reference, the solution that I obtained is shown below:

$$y(t)=\begin{cases}
\frac{A_0}{\omega_0}\big(t+\tau+\frac{1}{\omega_0}\big)\left[e^{-\omega_0(t+\tau)}-e^{-\omega_0(t-\tau)}\right]&,t\geq\tau \\
\frac{A_0}{\omega_0^2}-\frac{A_0}{\omega_0}\left(t+\tau+\frac{1}{\omega_0}\right)e^{-\omega_0(t+\tau)}&,|t|<\tau\\
0&,t\leq-\tau
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Can you add the main steps of the Fourier transform calculation? There could be a sign error somewhere. $$(e^{ω_0t}y(t))''=A_0e^{ω_0t}I(t)$$ should integrate to a continuous function.

Comment: I used the convention $\mathcal{F}(y(t))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}y(t)e^{-i\omega t}dt$ and arrived at $$(\omega_0^2-\omega^2+2\omega_0\omega i)\mathcal{F}(y(t))=A_0\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{\sin(\tau\omega)}{\omega}$$ Can you show us the further steps?

Comment: Sorry for slow reply, I decided to sleep on it. I'll take another look at it and then post the steps if I still can't find something wrong.